# Cómo armar el enlace sacando la información de este python y convertirla en una función javascript

Tags: javascript, python

No sé nada de python, pero lo que me interesa es entender cómo va construído el enlace *https://api.stadiamaps.com/route* ya que observando el código, lleva la key y los parametros del body además del costing que pues significa que es en auto la ruta... todo esto arroja el json, según yo, es una petición HTTP por lo cual el código python es opcional... entonces, cómo puedo construir el link con todos los parametros de la forma correcta y convertir ese ejemplo python pero en una función javascript para obtener el json?

```
import requests

def get_route_between_two_points(start_lat, start_lon, end_lat, end_lon, costing='auto'):
    params = {
        'api_key': YOUR_API_KEY,
    }

    body = {
        'locations': [
            {
                'lat': start_lat,
                'lon': start_lon,
                'type': 'break'
            },
            {
                'lat': end_lat,
                'lon': end_lon,
                'type': 'break'
            }
        ],
        'costing': costing,
    }

    r = requests.get('https://api.stadiamaps.com/route', params=params, json=body)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: El snippet solo es para código HTML, css y JS

Comment: para JavaScript es casi lo mismo, solo que los parámetros los especificas en la ruta, por ejemplo `fetch(\`ruta.com?api_key=${api_key}\`, { method:"POST"})` y el body se lo envías en el campo `body`, puedes investigar sobre `fetch` de JavaScript si tienes alguna duda

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? No pretendas que lo hagan todo por ti.

Comment: @MauricioContreras No necesito que lo hagan por mi, lo único que describe la pregunta es cómo va a armado el link para yo mismo obtener el json...

Comment: Con lo que te dije e investigando sobre `fetch` puedes resolver tu problema y responder a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En javascript, para hacer peticiones se utiliza [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Conociendo esta función, la conversión es bastante directa. Te adjunto un código funcional:

```js
async function get_route_between_two_points(start_lat, start_lon, end_lat, end_lon,costing = 'auto') {
  let url = 'https://api.stadiamaps.com/route'
  const body = {
    locations: [
      {
        lon: start_lon,
        lat: start_lat,
        type: 'break'
      },
      {
        side_of_street: 'right',
        lon: end_lon,
        lat: end_lat,
        type: 'break'
      }
    ],
    'costing': costing
  }

  const API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
  const URL_REQUEST = `${url}?api_key=${API_KEY}&json=${JSON.stringify(body)}`

  const r = await fetch(URL_REQUEST)
  return r.status == 200 ? r.json() : null
}

// Prueba
get_route_between_two_points(59.436886, 24.742596, 59.435562, 24.747604).then((data) => console.log(data))
```

La salida del código anterior después de que remplaces tu `'YOUR_API_KEY'` por tu clave personal, o bien lo ejecutes en el dominio `localhost` es:

```
{
  "trip": {
    "locations": [
      {
        "type": "break",
        "lat": 59.436886,
        "lon": 24.742596,
        "original_index": 0
      },
      {
        "type": "break",
        "lat": 59.435562,
        "lon": 24.747604,
        "city": "right",
        "original_index": 1
      }
    ],
    "legs": [
      {
        "maneuvers": [
          {
            "type": 1,
            "instruction": "Drive southwest on Rataskaevu.",
            "verbal_pre_transition_instruction": "Drive southwest on Rataskaevu. Then Make a sharp left onto Dunkri.",
            "verbal_post_transition_instruction": "Continue for 20 meters.",
            "street_names": [
              "Rataskaevu"
            ],
            "time": 3.196,
            "length": 0.017,
            "cost": 9.143,
            "begin_shape_index": 0,
            "end_shape_index": 2,
            "verbal_multi_cue": true,
            "travel_mode": "drive",
            "travel_type": "car"
          },
          {
            "type": 14,
            "instruction": "Make a sharp left onto Dunkri.",
            "verbal_transition_alert_instruction": "Make a sharp left onto Dunkri.",
            "verbal_pre_transition_instruction": "Make a sharp left onto Dunkri.",
            "verbal_post_transition_instruction": "Continue for 100 meters.",
            "street_names": [
              "Dunkri"
            ],
            "time": 31.108,
            "length": 0.131,
            "cost": 686.042,
            "begin_shape_index": 2,
            "end_shape_index": 11,
            "has_time_restrictions": true,
            "travel_mode": "drive",
            "travel_type": "car"
          },
          {
            "type": 10,
            "instruction": "Turn right onto Raekoja plats.",
            "verbal_transition_alert_instruction": "Turn right onto Raekoja plats.",
            "verbal_pre_transition_instruction": "Turn right onto Raekoja plats. Then Turn right onto Kullassepa.",
            "verbal_post_transition_instruction": "Continue for 10 meters.",
            "street_names": [
              "Raekoja plats"
            ],
            "time": 3.39,
            "length": 0.013,
            "cost": 13.273,
            "begin_shape_index": 11,
            "end_shape_index": 13,
            "has_time_restrictions": true,
            "verbal_multi_cue": true,
            "travel_mode": "drive",
            "travel_type": "car"
          },
          {
            "type": 10,
            "instruction": "Turn right onto Kullassepa.",
            "verbal_transition_alert_instruction": "Turn right onto Kullassepa.",
            "verbal_pre_transition_instruction": "Turn right onto Kullassepa.",
            "verbal_post_transition_instruction": "Continue for 70 meters.",
            "street_names": [
              "Kullassepa"
            ],
            "time": 13.876,
            "length": 0.073,
            "cost": 25.153,
            "begin_shape_index": 13,
            "end_shape_index": 15,
            "has_time_restrictions": true,
            "travel_mode": "drive",
            "travel_type": "car"
          },
          {
            "type": 15,
            "instruction": "Turn left onto Kuninga.",
            "verbal_transition_alert_instruction": "Turn left onto Kuninga.",
            "verbal_pre_transition_instruction": "Turn left onto Kuninga.",
            "verbal_post_transition_instruction": "Continue for 80 meters.",
            "street_names": [
              "Kuninga"
            ],
            "time": 20.811,
            "length": 0.075,
            "cost": 44.549,
            "begin_shape_index": 15,
            "end_shape_index": 19,
            "has_time_restrictions": true,
            "travel_mode": "drive",
            "travel_type": "car"
          },
          {
            "type": 10,
            "instruction": "Turn right onto Suur-Karja.",
            "verbal_transition_alert_instruction": "Turn right onto Suur-Karja.",
            "verbal_pre_transition_instruction": "Turn right onto Suur-Karja.",
            "verbal_post_transition_instruction": "Continue for 100 meters.",
            "street_names": [
              "Suur-Karja"
            ],
            "time": 25.777,
            "length": 0.14,
            "cost": 63.973,
            "begin_shape_index": 19,
            "end_shape_index": 29,
            "has_time_restrictions": true,
            "travel_mode": "drive",
            "travel_type": "car"
          },
          {
            "type": 5,
            "instruction": "Your destination is on the right.",
            "verbal_transition_alert_instruction": "Your destination will be on the right.",
            "verbal_pre_transition_instruction": "Your destination is on the right.",
            "time": 0,
            "length": 0,
            "cost": 0,
            "begin_shape_index": 29,
            "end_shape_index": 29,
            "travel_mode": "drive",
            "travel_type": "car"
          }
        ],
        "summary": {
          "has_time_restrictions": true,
          "min_lat": 59.435603,
          "min_lon": 24.742472,
          "max_lat": 59.437065,
          "max_lon": 24.747662,
          "time": 98.162,
          "length": 0.45,
          "cost": 842.137
        },
        "shape": "wsvjpBomden@v@x@~EdG]cEc@{Fm@uF]oDgAwJ{Eu_@iB}SeAmUo@qW`CwATyDdNxCfXjGaByL}@eVUwHiAga@lIoP|EuFvKaSxBqEtEgKdDyLnA{HbAcHvA}G\\sA"
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "has_time_restrictions": true,
      "min_lat": 59.435603,
      "min_lon": 24.742472,
      "max_lat": 59.437065,
      "max_lon": 24.747662,
      "time": 98.162,
      "length": 0.45,
      "cost": 842.137
    },
    "status_message": "Found route between points",
    "status": 0,
    "units": "kilometers",
    "language": "en-US"
  }
}
```